# prepare dynamic where with [Op.and] in sequelize

Tags: sequelize.js

I have :

```
const arr=['a','b','c']
```

I want

```
where:{
 [Op.and]:{text:arr[0]},
 [Op.and]:{text:arr[1]},
 [Op.and]:{text:arr[2]}
}
```

Don't need hard coded solution because my array size can vary.
I want to match all `text` or `none`

```
return Models.Question.findAll({ 
where:{
 [Op.and]:{text:arr[0]},
 [Op.and]:{text:arr[1]},
 [Op.and]:{text:arr[2]}
}
```

})